# How to label a bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a very simple bar chart ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X02rS.png)).

I have two questions:

First, how can I label the bars? I've managed to label one stack correctly, but I don't know how I label the other one without changing them both. I want shaded be labelled with 76 and exposed with 277?

Second, how do I change the colour of the columns, say I wanted red and blue for example?

Thanks

```
my_data <-  read.csv("geum_data.csv")

graph <-ggplot(my_data, aes(exposure, seedling.count, fill = exposure)) + 
geom_col(width = 0.5) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)))+
geom_text(aes(label= 76), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
labs(fill = "Exposure")
graph <-  graph + labs(x = "Exposure", y = "Seedling Count avg.")
print (graph)
```

Comment: Hi @TomG888. Can you post some sample data in dput format? Simply type `dput(my_data)` in the console and copy the output into your post. Or, if your dataset is large use `dput(head(my_data, 20))` to post only the first 20 rows.

Comment: BTW: you forgot to include the screenshot in your post. (;

Answer (score 1):

To add the labels simply map the variable with the values on label (from your screenshot I guessed that you want to add `seedling.count`). Changing the colour can be achieved via `scale_fill_manual`. Try this:

```
graph <- ggplot(my_data, aes(exposure, seedling.count, fill = exposure)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Exposed = "red", Shaded = "blue")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = seedling.count), position = position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25) +
  labs(fill = "Exposure")

graph <- graph + labs(x = "Exposure", y = "Seedling Count avg.")
graph
```

Using `mtcars` as example data the following code shows an example of this approach:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = mpg), vjust=-0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`4` = "red", `6` = "blue", `8` = "green"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>